# Is my solution to this inequality/optimisation problem correct?

Tags: inequality

The question goes like this: Let x and y be two (real) numbers such that:

x-y≤2, 5x+3y≤15 and 5x+y≥5. Find the largest possible value of 2x+3y.

I first attempted to prove that if 2x+3y is maximised, than either 5x+3y=15 or x-y=2. I did this with a proof by contradiction.

Suppose that there exists $x_1,y_1$ such that $2x_1+3y_1$ is maximised and $x_1-y_1<2,5x_1+3y_1<15$ and $5x_1+y_1≥5$ Let $x_1-y_1=b$ and $5x_1+3y_1=b$. (a<2 and b<15)

Let $=min(2-a,\frac{15-b}{5}$).

Set $x'=x_1+$

$x'+y_1=x_1+y_1+≤a+2-a=2≤2$

$5x'+3y_1=5x_1+3y_1+5≤b+5\left(\frac{15-b}{5}\right)=15≤15$

$5x'+y_1=5x_1+y_1+5>5$

since $2-a>0$ and $\frac{15-b}{5}>0$, meaning $>0$

Hence, it is always possible to find some $x'>x$ which satisfies the original three ineqalities if neither $x-y=2$ nor $5x+3y=15$, which means that $2x'+3y>2x+3y$

All that is left is to set $x-y=2$ or $5x+3y=15$.

(1):

$x-y=2$

$\rightarrow x=y+2$

$5x+3y≤15$

$8y≤5$

$y≤\frac{5}{8}$

$5x+y≥5$

$6y≥-5$

$y≤-\frac{5}{6}<\frac{5}{8}$

This means the maximum possible values of x and y are $\frac{7}{6}$ and $\frac{-5}{6}$ if $x-y=2$, meaning $2x+3y=-\frac{1}{6}$

(2):

$5x+3y=15$

$\rightarrow 5x=15-3y$

$5x+y=15-2y≥5$

$y≤5$

$x-y≤2$

$5x-5y≤10$

$15-8y≤10$

$y≥\frac{5}{8}$

This means the maximum possible y is 5, which yields x=0 when substituted into 5x+3y=0. This means the maximum possible value of 2x+3y is 15, which is larger than $-\frac{1}{6}$

Is my solution correct, and is there a simpler way?

Comment: There is. Draw the graphs, find the common region and use the corner point theorem

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your solution is correct. For further insights into this kind of optimization problems I suggest you look at linear programming. For instance, using this method, you could solve this problem in a geometrical way. By drawing the feasible set, we get:[image: Drawing of the feasible set]

We know that the optimal solution, if there exists one, will necessarily be an extreme point of the feasible set. Therefore we could just try each point one by one and find the optimal solution.